# XEP-0060 pubsub auto subscribe node to other users Smack

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd, smack

I am implementing pubsub model to achieve group chat. All things are     working well. I am able to create node, other users subscribe the node, publish item by owner or subscriber and item is getting to all subscriber.

Now i have requirement, the owner(User creating node) should be able to subscribe node to roster users and subscribed user start getting item publish.
Is there any way to achieve this?
My node creation code is below:

```
ConfigureForm form = new ConfigureForm(DataForm.Type.submit);
form.setPersistentItems(false);
form.setDeliverPayloads(true);
form.setAccessModel(AccessModel.open);
form.setPublishModel(PublishModel.open);
setSubscribers(form);
LeafNode node = (LeafNode) manager.createNode(nodeName, form);
```

Comment: What did you try ? What was the result ?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I tried to subscribe node as node.subscribe("771126@local.echat.com"); // jid that i want to subscribe my node created by me(my jid 142491@local.echat.com). 

Error in Smack console: XMPPError: bad-request - modify
Ejabberd.log in second comment.

Comment: Ejabberd.log:
D(<0.1029.0>:ejabberd_c2s:1553) : Send XML on stream = <<"<iq from='pubsub.local.echat.com' to='142491@local.echat.com/Smack' type='error' xml:lang='en' id='Jnoyz-25'><pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'><subscribe node='testNode123' jid='771126@local.echat.com'/></pubsub><error code='400' type='modify'><bad-request xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><invalid-jid xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#errors'/></error></iq>">>

Comment: Hi Dharmraj, I need the same thing, to use it with new MIX protocol. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi theMoonlitknight, No, i have not found any solution.  That was not our require anymore we move to MUC, not using PUBSUB.

Answer (score 0):

As document says it is possible to autosubscribe to a node, based on access model which may be roster/presence/open access model.